# Access vuex store from catch block

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

Im trying to put error messages from an api call and put it in the vuex store, but im not sure how to do it.

I have this in a "method" within a vue file

```
 axios
    .post("/api/model", this.model)
    .then(response => {
      window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      if (error.response) {
        this.$store.commit("setServerErrors", error.response.data);
      }
    });
```

Im getting the following error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined

Comment: change the function to a arrow one, you are losing the `this` scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your function is reassigning the value of `this`.

Try changing it to:

```
axios
    .post("/api/model", this.model)
    .then(response => {
      window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
    })
    .catch(error => {  // <= HERE IS THE CHANGE!!
      if (error.response) {
        this.$store.commit("setServerErrors", error.response.data);
      }
    });
```

Read about the difference between `function(arg) {}`and `(arg) => {}`here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

You are using a function instead of an arrow function on the catch block so `this` inside that block has a different scope.

Just replace the function with an arrow function.

```
axios
    .post("/api/model", this.model)
    .then(response => {
      window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.response) {
        this.$store.commit("setServerErrors", error.response.data);
      }
    });
```